# Cmake project with usage requirements

Tags: linux, cmake

I am currently trying to setup a C++ project with the following structure:

```
GUI
| CMakeLists.txt
| deps/
| | src/
| | install/
| src/
| | GLWindows/
| | | GLWindow.h
| | RocketShell/
| | | CMakeLists.txt
| | | RocketShell.h
| | | RocketShell.cpp
| | | ShellInterfaces/
```

My idea is then to build `RocketShell` as a library and then link it to an executable added in the top CMakelists file. Note that I am also using the `deps` directory for storing, compiling and installing the dependencies for my project. Some of my dependencies are for example: boost, glfw, libRocket.

I am trying to get the `RocketShell` target to export its usage requirements by using `target_include_directories`, `target_link_libraries`, and `target_compile_options` with the corresponding `PUBLIC` mode.

The problem is that the requirements are not being exported. The top CMakeLists file is able to create and use the `RocketShell` target, but it can not see the exported variables.

I am trying to do the project configuration in the "modern" way. I just started to learn cmake, so I will appreciate if you could point me in the right direction. Thanks.

### The top CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.0) 
project(GUI)

set(DEPS_INSTALL_PREFIX ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/deps/install CACHE PATH "Installation directory's prefix for the dependencies")

add_subdirectory(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/RocketShell)

link_directories(${DEPS_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib)

add_executable(GUI src/main.cpp src/GLWindows/GLFWWindow.h src/GLWindows/GLFWWindow.cpp)
target_link_libraries(GUI RocketShell)
```

### The RocketShell CMakeLists.txt file

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)

project (RocketShell VERSION 0.1 LANGUAGES C CXX)

# find GLFW
include(${DEPS_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib/cmake/glfw/glfwConfig.cmake)
link_directories(${DEPS_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib)

file(GLOB ${PROJECT_NAME}_SRCS ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/ShellInterfaces/*.cpp)
list(APPEND ${PROJECT_NAME}_SRCS ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/RocketShell.cpp)

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} SHARED ${${PROJECT_NAME}_SRCS})

target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/RocketShell> $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:$<INSTALL_PREFIX>/RocketShell>)
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/RocketShell/ShellInterfaces)
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${DEPS_INSTALL_PREFIX}/include)


target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC glfw ${OPENGL_glu_LIBRARY} ${GLFW_LIBRARIES} ${GLEW_LIBRARIES}
   boost_thread boost_system boost_log boost_log_setup boost_filesystem GLEW GL
    RocketControls RocketCore RocketDebugger)

target_compile_options(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE -DBOOST_LOG_DYN_LINK -std=c++0x)
```

## Solution

The problem was that I was not exporting the `-DBOOST_LOG_DYN_LINK` definition, for that reason the GUI target was unable to link against boost_log. The transitive usage requirements propagation works like a charm. 
To solve the issue just replace `PRIVATE` by `PUBLIC` in the following line in the RocketShell subdirectory CMakeLists file:

```
target_compile_options(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE -DBOOST_LOG_DYN_LINK -std=c++0x)
```

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "can not see the exported variables"? Do you get some error?

Comment: Hi Peter,
Whenever I make use of the requirements that should be exported by the `RocketShell` target the compilation fails. Note that the `RocketShell` target exports the boost_log library as a requirement. When I try to use it in the `GUI` target at the top CMakeLists file, the linking phase fails. For proving this I removed the `GLWindows` from the target and left it like this:
`add_executable(GUI src/main.cpp)`
while the main contains this single line, and the corresponding include directory:
`BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(info) << "LOGGING";`

Comment: @ruslo thanks for answering but first of all that is not my issue(that part is working perfectly), and second of all, if I know the directory well the boost libraries are installed I can link to a specific library directly.

Comment: Hi @ruslo, what I meant by that is that the RocketShell target should export its usage requirements for the GUI target to consume. The question wasn't oriented to boost, was about my use of the cmake commands. Anyways I found the error. The problem was that I wasn't exporting the `-DBOOST_LOG_DYN_LINK` definition, which was required for GUI to link against boost_log.